# Trying to figure out the step between installing Wine and getting Sims 3 to play

Tags: wine, games, steam

My tech friend did me a solid and gave me a copy of Ubuntu to load onto my new drive since I can't currently afford a Windows OS. It's great, fairly user-friendly for anyone who has done bare-minimum programming.

However, I've hit a small snafu and I'm having some issues understanding the tech-speak in the forums where answers are hosted.

Problem: I want to play Sims 3 via Steam on my shiny new Ubuntu OS.

Solution: Install Wine

Problem: Now what?

I've got winehq-stable installed, but there seems to be an interim step that I'm missing to make the program work and to make Sims 3 function. From what I understand there may be a third-party program of some sort to control Wine?

Y'all, I just wanna play my dumb game and build stupid physics-defying houses. I don't wanna bother my tech friend because a) he lost his damn phone and the only way I can get in touch with him is by hoping his alcoholism drags his ass to the bar down the street where I can find him, and b) by the time he is at the bar he is always too messed up to use the terminal reliably and he doesn't understand the questions I ask him.

Extra info: I can't even install the Sims 3 files onto my system via Steam. From what I understand on the forums I just have to right-click the files and run them thru wine, but I'm not sure how to proceed. SS of error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7D2Z.jpg

Halp? In ELI5 terminology if possible.

Comment: Are you trying use the windows version on ubuntu or the ubuntu version?  Can try this and not worry about using wine.   https://itsfoss.com/install-steam-ubuntu-linux/

Answer (score 0):

Reddit helped me with a super, super easy solution: enable ProtonBeta within Steam!

Steam > settings > steamplay > turn everything on.